# Subviews of animated UIView not keeping their constraints during animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I'm animating a custom UIView to expand, as shown in the gif below (the red view).
When clicking the open/close-button, I want the left icon to stay in its superview's center, vertically. As shown below, as soon as I click the button, the icon will pop to where it should be after the animation is done.
The same goes for the button, but it's not as noticeable as it gets temporarily hidden from clicking it.

I was also hoping for the `UILabel` in between to animate its size, rather than popping to minimum height as soon as you click 'Close'.

In Storyboard I have set the icon and button to align center with the superview, which to me seems to be the correct way to achieve what I want. I would assume that when I animate the superview, that the subviews would stay center during the animation, but instead they instantly move to the point that WILL be correct, but after the animation is completed.

[image: gif]

My animation code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in

    var rect = self.frame; //The current frame, to change
    let oldHeight = self.frame.size.height as CGFloat

    let newSize = self.sizeForBanner() //Get the CGSize for the big banner.

    if(self.isBig) //Animate to big size
    {
        //Put the new height and origin for the large version of the view
        rect.size.height = newSize.height;
        rect.origin.y -= (rect.size.height - oldHeight)

    }else{ //Animate to small size

        //Put the new height and origin for the small version of the view

        rect.size.height = self.minimalHeight;
        rect.origin.y += oldHeight-rect.size.height
    }

        //Set the new variables
        self.frame = rect;

    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
        //Completion
}
```

How /what do I change to make the icon and the button to stay centered when the superview animates?..

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: @AviTsadok Yeah, I think so! I don't have the code here right now, but I can check later, and write it as an answer. I think it was something with enabling `view.clipsToBounds` (or what it's called) and a few other variables. And be sure to have your constraints in order

Comment: @AviTsadok Actually, I don't have that code anymore. We ended up using a slightly different design, but it was not because of this problem. I am fairly certain that I managed to make this work by changing the constraints somewhat, and changing some of the values, like `clipsToBounds` and such. I remember there was an 'aha'-moment when I realized that I had to set `clipsToBounds` to `true` in the *superview* and not the actual view (or the other way around, or.. something). It was important which object had these properties, and it was the opposite of what I thought. Good luck, and sorry:)

Comment: I solved it by unchecking 'Autoresize Subviews' which lies just below 'clip subviews'. Someone in need may give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `Clip Subviews` enabled. This is a value that is disabled by default for UIViews.

If you created the view through Interface Builder go to `Attributes Inspector` and check the `Clip Subviews` checkbox:

[image]

If you created the view through code then use:

```
view.clipsToBounds = true
```